# Asp net послать post запрос с редиректом

Tags: asp.net

есть ли возможность передать данные Post запросом, с переходом на нужный ресурс. что-то вроде

```
string URI = "http://localhost/";
string myParameters = "identName="+ identName;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["identName"] = identName;
    var response = wc.UploadValues(URI, "POST", data);
}
```

но этот код не отрабатывает

Comment: после `var response = ...` очевидно надо посмотреть в этот `response`, не содержит ли он инструкцию редиректа. И если что перенастроить `webclient` (или новый сделать) на новый URI (который будет указан в response) и выполнить новый запрос методом `GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string URI = "http://localhost/";

Response.Clear();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", URI);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{0}'>", identName);
// Other params go here
sb.Append("</form>");
sb.Append("</body>");
sb.Append("</html>");

Response.Write(sb.ToString());

Response.End();
```

оригинал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get

Comment: Это серверный код, который просто генерирует html c клиентским постом на новый url. WebClient, который у вас приведен в вопросе, скрипт выполнять не умеет, и просто вернет вот этот html как строчку в response. Т.е. код из вопроса + код из ответа вместе не заработают :(